# Is $\text{BRANCH}(n)$ finite for $n > 2$?

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory, trees, big-numbers

> Is $\text{BRANCH}(n)$ finite for $n > 2$? Define $\text{BRANCH}(n)$ as
> the maximum length of a string that is composed of at most $n$ unique
> characters AND meets the following condition:
>
> Define a substring as all letters from positions $i$ to $2i$
> (inclusive) (where $i= 1, 2, 3...$). Then, a certain substring must
> not be allowed to have previous substrings embedded in it, or else the
> branch stops.

$\text{BRANCH}(1) = 3$, since the longest string is `aaa`. The first substring from positions $1$ to $2$ is `aa`. The theoretical substring from positions $2$ to $4$ would be `aaa`. However, since `aa`(substring from $1$ to $2$) is embedded inside `aaa` (substring from $2$ to $4$), we cannot make our string `aaaa` and stop at `aaa`.

$\text{BRANCH}(2) = 11$, since the longest string is `abbbaaaaaaa`. At positions $1$ to $2$, we have substring `ab`. At positions $2$ to $4$, we have substring `bbb`. `ab` isn't embedded in this, we move on.

At positions $3$ to $6$, we have substring `bbaa`. None of `ab` or `bbb` are embedded in this, we move on.

At positions $4$ to $8$, we have substring `baaaa`. None of `ab`, `bbb`, and `bbaa` are embedded in this, we move on.

At positions $5$ to $10$, we have substring `aaaaaa`. None of `ab`, `bbb`, `bbaa`, and `baaaa` are embedded in this, we move on.

However, there's a problem here, since the next sequence from $6$ to $12$ will embed at least one of the previous substrings, so we just add a letter at position $11$ and stop.

I can reason that $$\text{BRANCH}(3)\geq1+10\sum_{i=1}^{10}\sum_{j=1}^{10-i}{10 \choose i}{10 - i \choose j}=570021$$
The true value for $\text{BRANCH}(3)$, if finite, is likely much larger. Moreover, is there any way to prove that $\text{BRANCH}(n)$ is contained by $\text{TREE}(n)$ (a "$1$-dimensional" version of $\text{TREE}(n)$)?.

**EDIT: For clarification on "embedding"**

For any substring $S_i$: [$i$, $2i$], there is a set of previous substrings {$S_k$: [$k$, $2k$]}, where $k = 1,2,..., i-1$. If any member of this set is a valid substring of $S_i$ (that is, if it's the same as $S_i$ from positions $a$ to $b$ for any $a$ and $b$ where $0 \leq a < b \leq i+1$), then that member is "embedded" in $S_i$ and the sequence ends at length $2i - 1$. As an example, consider the string `abaaab`. The substring $S_3$ from position $3$ to $6$ is `aaab`. In the set of previous substrings {$S_1$,$S_2$} = {`ab`, `baa`}, $S_1$(`ab`) is the same as $S_3$(`aaab`) from position $3$ to $4$, so $S_1$ is embedded in $S_3$.

Comment: It seems from your examples your strings are formed using only 2 letters. With no extra conditions, are there not only a finite number of strings using at most n distinct characters?

Comment: @coffeemath It uses at most $n$ distinct characters, but the characters can be repeated (e.g. `aa` is a valid string, and so is `aaa`, and so on).

Comment: What exactly means "embedded"? Would "ab" be embedded in "acb"?

Comment: @Ingix No, it wouldn't.

Comment: @edit_profile You're still not saying what "embedded" means! Does it refer to all substrings, or only ones in positions $i$ through $2i$ (in which case `aa` wouldn't be embedded in `baa`)? Please edit your question to give a definition.

Comment: @MishaLavrov I added an edit, hopefully that clears it up

Answer (score 1):

For a given $n\geq 2$, let $S=(s_1,s_2,\ldots)$ be an infinite sequence of elements in $\{3,\ldots,n+2\}$.

For $i\geq 1$, let $S_i:=S[i:2i]$ be the subsequence $S_i=(s_i,s_{i+1},\ldots,s_{2i})$. We build a rooted tree $T_i$ on $i+1$ vertices as follow. Start with $T_i$ being a single vertex, the root of $T_i$. For $k$ in $0,\ldots,i$:

1. Let $v$ be any vertex of $T_i$ at distance $k$ from the root.
2. Add $s_{k+i}$ vertices all adjacent with $v$

This process stops with a rooted tree, with bounded degree $\Delta(T_i)\leq n+2$, and with no vertices of degree $2$. Ignoring the leaves, it has degree sequence exactly $S_i$ (ordered by distance to the root).

By [Kruskal tree theorem](https://www.cambridge.org/core/journals/mathematical-proceedings-of-the-cambridge-philosophical-society/article/on-wellquasiordering-finite-trees/F0EA9810607357E1FE47823CCFA79E00?utm_campaign=shareaholic&utm_medium=copy_link&utm_source=bookmark), there exist $i < j$ such that and $T_i$ is homeomorphic to a subtree of $T_j$. Given that $T_j$ contains no vertex of degree $2$, then $T_i$ is isomorphic to a subtree of $T_j$. Which imlies that $S_i$ is contained in $S_j$. QED